# How to remove albhabet and leading zero in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have code in SQL Server to remove characters from variable

```
DECLARE @textval NVARCHAR(30)
SET @textval = 'CHA000382486'

SELECT 
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(@textval, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', @textval), 8000), PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(@textval, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', @textval), 8000) + 'X') -1)
```

And also different code to remove leading zeros

```
DECLARE @textval2 NVARCHAR(30)

SET @textval2 = '000382486'

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(@textval2, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', @textval2+'.'), LEN(@textval2))
```

But I want a single piece of code which would be able to remove alphabets and leading zero.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you convert to `(big)int` you loose your leading zero's (of course after removing other chars). If you then convert back to `varchar` again, you have your original datatype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will find the first numeric (non-zero) value

```
Declare @textval NVARCHAR(30) = 'CHA000382486'
Select Substring(@textval,PatIndex('%[1-9]%',@textval),len(@textval))
```

Returns

```
382486
```

Another option

```
Select ''+cast(right(@textval,9) as int)
```